# How do I change scroll wheel sensitivity in Xubuntu 12.10 64-bit?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

Exactly what it says on the tin. Googled, sifted through a few results from 2+ years ago, and no luck.

This is a serious pain to my right index finger. I'm using Chromium, and it scrolls about three lines per click.